# Getting different result for django cell attribute in method vs unittest

Tags: python, django, nose

Work project using Django which has tables, rows, columns, and cells.  Column has a reject() method which is supposed to set is_rejected bool attribute to True for the column and then all cells associated with that column.  Debug lines in the reject() method look like it is working but assertions in unittests find is_rejected to be False for the associated cells.

I thought there might be a race condition where the assertion happened before the process of finding and changing the cells completed so I put in a wait for five seconds after the column.reject() but before the assertion.  Still failed.

I thought I might have been checking the wrong cell in the unit tests so I verified the cell values vs the cell value reported in the debug lines, changing the value a few times to see that they changed in the debug output which they did.

I've been over and over the variable names to make sure I didn't make a dumb mistake, and if I did I still can't see it.

this is the reject method in Column (including debug lines):

```
class Column(BaseModel):

    def reject(self):
        super().reject()

        #reject all cells associated with this Column
        for cell in self.cell_set.all():
            print("cell: ", cell)
            print("rejected: ", cell.is_rejected)
            cell.reject()
            print("rejected: ", cell.is_rejected)
```

This is the relevant test:

```
def test_reject_column_rejects_associated_cells(self):
        self.tb2 = Table.create(
            team_name='FooBarTeam',
            app_name='FooBarApp',
            config_name='FooBarConfig2',
            app_description='FooBarTeamDescription',
            created_by=self.user
        )

        self.co3 = Column.create(
            table_id=self.tb2.id,
            column_name="Bar",
            created_by=self.user,
            created_reason="Foo reason",
            column_default="abc",
            regex_ids=[],
            column_type="str"
        ) 

        self.rw4 = Row.create(
            created_by=self.user,
            table=self.tb2,
            columns=['Bar'],
            row_data=['123'],
            reason='FooReason'
        )

        self.cl3 = Cell.create(
           created_by = self.user,
            value = "Foo!",
            row = self.rw4,
            column = self.co3,
            reason = "FooReason"
        )

        self.assertEqual(
            self.cl3.is_rejected,
            False
        )

        self.assertEqual(
            self.co3.is_rejected,
            False
        )

        self.co3.reject()

        self.assertEqual(
            self.co3.is_rejected,
            True
        )

        #this is the only assertion that fails
        self.assertEqual(
            self.cl3.is_rejected,
            True
        )
```

This is the unittest call just to run the one unit test, note the debug lines show correct behavior with the cell.is_rejected attribute flipping to True:

```
>python manage.py test tests/model_tests/test_config_models.py:ConfigReviewModelTest.test_reject_column_rejects_associated_cells

nosetests tests/model_tests/test_config_models.py:ConfigReviewModelTest.test_reject_column_rejects_associated_cells --with-coverage --cover-package=audit,config,config_importer,login,peer_review,tools,ui --exclude-dir=tests/functional_tests/test_ui --exclude-dir=tests/unit_tests --cover-html --cover-erase --cover-branches --verbosity=1

Creating test database for alias 'default'...

F

======================================================================

FAIL: test_reject_column_rejects_associated_cells (tests.model_tests.test_config_models.ConfigReviewModelTest)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\dev_env\config-manager-env\config-manager\tests\model_tests\test_config_models.py", line 1000, in test_reject_column_rejects_associated_cells

    True

AssertionError: False != True

-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
cell:  Foo! - Bar
cell column:  Bar
rejected:  False
rejected:  True

cell:  123 - Bar
cell column:  Bar
rejected:  False
rejected:  True
--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `reject` method is actually saving the changes that you make to the Python object to the database, for both the column and the associated cells, i.e. `column.save()` and `cell.save()`. Then in your test once you call reject on the column, `self.co3.reject()`, you will need to refresh your cell Python object by reading it from the database again.

```
    self.cl3.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(
        self.cl3.is_rejected,
        True
    )
```

Your printed out tests in the reject function work because you are calling reject on the objects and then printing the fields from those same objects.

Comment: The reject baseModel method (which cell inherits) does call .save() but I did not realize that my unit test was not reading from the DB but was instead essentially looking at a cached copy.  I added a self.cl3.refresh_from_db() after self.co.reject() in the unittest and it appears to be working.  Thank you!

Comment: Ya I guessed that it might but wanted to mention it. Glad it helped!